# What's the difference between DOCUMENT_URI and URI_REQUEST in SSI?

Tags: apache, ssi

When looking at a SSI printenv dump I see a variable URI_REQUEST.

When reading the Apache mod_include docs I see DOCUMENT_URI which they define as "The (%-decoded) URL path of the document requested by the user."

Anyone know the difference between the two?

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

REQUEST_URI includes the Query String (?q=testing...) where DOCUMENT_URI does not.

Comment: There are some other differences: for example, if some rewrite rules occur (without the proxy option), REQUEST_URI contains the genuine URL, DOCUMENT_URI the rewritten one.